# Why does redlib define INT8_MIN as (-0x80) and not as (-0x7F) or (-INT8_MAX - 1)

Tags: c, misra

As the title says, REDLIB defines INT8_MIN as (-0x80). This is giving warnings when using QAC to check for MISRA-C compatibility: (the same goes for INT16 and INT32, which are -0x8000 and -0x80000000 respectively)

```
Msg(4:1281) Integer literal constant is of an unsigned type but does not include a "U" suffix.
MISRA-C:2004 Rule 10.6; REFERENCE - ISO:C90-6.1.3.2 (Integer Constants)

Msg(4:3101) Unary '-' applied to an operand of type unsigned int or unsigned long gives an unsigned result.
MISRA-C:2004 Rule 12.9; REFERENCE - ISO:C90-6.3.3.3 Unary Arithmetic Operators - Semantics

Msg(4:2850) Constant: Implicit conversion to a signed integer type of insufficient size.
MISRA-C:2004 Rule 3.1; REFERENCE - ISO:C90-6.2.1.2 Conversions (to Signed Integers)
```

Comment: Because other values would be wrong. You could "heal" the warning keeping the correct value with some casting. But apparently, the developers of redlib are not concerned about Misra.

Comment: @undur_gongor There is not really any sensible way you can "heal" anything here, without rewriting the code. `-65536` instead of `-0x8000` would have been MISRA compliant. So would `-(int16_t)0x8000`, although such a line doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Lundin `(int16_t)0x8000` is an out-of-range conversion (causing implementation-defined behaviour)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a subtle rule about integer literals ("integer constants") in the C standard (C11 6.4.4.1) stating that if you write a plain integer literal such as `70000` without any `U` or `L` suffix, the type of the literal is determined as follows:

- If the literal is large enough to be stored in an int, then it is of type int.
- Otherwise if the literal is large enough to stored in a long, then it is of type long.
- (Otherwise in case of C99/C11, the literal is of type long long).

So `70000` on a 16-bit system would be of type long.

But when you write a hexadecimal integer literal (or an octal one), different rules apply. Instead, the compiler is checking in this order:

```
int
unsigned int
long int
unsigned long int
long long int
unsigned long long int
```

So when you write `0x8000` on a system where int is 16 bits, the compiler checks: Can it fit inside an int? No. Can it fit inside an unsigned int? Yes. The type of `0x8000` is therefore unsigned int and similarly `0x80000000` is of type unsigned long.

This is why you get the MISRA errors for `0x8000` and `0x80000000`, because it simply doesn't make any sense to apply unary `-` on an unsigned type. So that library is not MISRA-C compliant.

*However*, the integer literal `0x80` is always of type `int` on any system. If you get a MISRA error on that line, your static analysis tool is broken for that rule. File a bug report to PRQA.

Comment: Our current processor is a 32 bit ARM NXP version so our base type is always 32 bits and not 16 bits,?

Comment: @DaanTimmer If INT16 is defined as `-0x8000` you are either using a 16 bit compiler, or your compiler is really weird. Sane compilers define short as 16 bits and int to the width of the data bus for the given CPU. But of course, C allows insane implementations too. I'd advise using a sane compiler...

Comment: The compiler used is GCC's arm-none-eabi-gcc shipped with NXP's LPCXpresso. `stdint.h` defines: `#define INT8_MIN (-0x80)` `#define INT16_MIN (-0x8000)` `#define INT32_MIN (-0x80000000)` and typedefs as: `typedef signed char int8_t;` `typedef short int16_t;` `typedef int int32_t;` I guess this is quite a sane compiler :-)

Comment: @DaanTimmer Hmm I probably just confused INT16_MIN with INT_MIN. Still, that makes both `0x80` and `0x8000` int and the analyser should not whine about them.

Comment: @DaanTimmer `-0x80000000` is just wrong there. File a bug report! It should be `(-0x7FFFFFFF - 1)` or equivalent. The other definitions are OK. BTW  edit that info into your question.

Comment: @DaanTimmer:  Tools targeting MISRA need to cater for different environments, for example they need to allow size and alignment of types to be changed.  This in turn impacts the analysis that would be expected.  PRQA's tools are configurable in this way too, so this may be a simple issue of configuration. (DISCLAIMER:  It's my day job)